# Get java object by id

Tags: java

What I am trying to achieve is to update an object's value with only his ID known:

1. How can I get the object with a corresponding ID?
2. So that I can update a property?

**class forest**

```
public class forest {
    public forestName;
    
    public forest(String forestName){
        this.forestName=forestName;
    }
    updateTreeName(int id, String Name){
        // Here I need to update the name of the tree with that specific ID
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        forest greenforest = new forest();
        // create some tree's in the greenforest.
        greenforest.updateTreeName(4, "red leafe");
    }
}
```

**class tree**

```
public class tree {
    public String treeName;
    public int id;
    public tree(int id, String treeName){
        this.treeName=treeName;
        this.id=id;
    }
}
```

Comment: There are lots of ways: keep a `Map<String, tree>` and find the `tree` object by the id. Implement a `.equals()` method on `tree` and put it into a `Set`; iterate over all of the `tree` objects looking at the name. The requirements will drive a better answer (edited `forest` to `tree`).

Comment: You iterate through your collection and make your changes.

Comment: Class names are generally capitalised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `HashMap` to keep objects. Then use the `get` method to get the object with the given id.

```
public class Forest {
    public String forestName;

    HashMap<Integer, Tree> trees = new HashMap<>();

    public Forest(String forestName){
        this.forestName=forestName;

        //initialize trees
        trees.put(4, new Tree(4, "redleaef"));
    }

    public void updateTreeName(int id, String Name){
        trees.get(id).treeName = Name;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Forest greenforest = new Forest("name");
        // create some tree's in the greenforest.
        greenforest.updateTreeName(4, "red leafe");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Your previous edit was also very hulpfull. I will accept this answer in 2 minutes (stackoverflow limit me)

Comment: In this answer, consider the fact that I only have the Id. Is it possible to access the Java managed memory and retrieve the object given the Id? (Shifting from C++, so still can't get over pointers)